# HTML & CSS - background-image:url not showing

Tags: html, css

Here is the html, for example:

```
<td class=topleft width=10 height=10></td>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
td.topleft{
    border:0px;
    width: 100px;
    background-image: url(images/topleft.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
```

the directory structure (starting with a folder on my desktop called site)

site.html

styles.css

/images/topleft.png

Note: styles are being populated from the css file otherwise.

I have tried an absolute path with file:

```
  background-image:url(file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/site/images/topleft.png);
```

If I put that url in my browser directly, the image is reachable and appears.

Comment: Could it be that you have `.png` in the stylesheet but the image is a `.jpg`?

Comment: no, its a png, just checked.

Comment: can you show the directory structure of `site.html` relative to `images/` ?

Comment: Have you tried multiple browsers? Cleared your cache? Tried the absolute path of `url(/images/topleft.png);`?

Comment: Try to use `background-color: red;` and check if you see your element or not.

Comment: You use `Inspect element` of browser to get real images's url.

Comment: I'd suggest: 1) Move the "images" folder to the location where the .css is, instead of having it in the root or desktop of your computer. 2) Remove the td width=10, height = 10, to see if that is affecting the display (10px x 10px).

Comment: @NOX, no that hasn't worked

Comment: Try giving the TD a height in the CSS.  It might be 100px wide by 0px high, in which case, no image would show up.

Comment: @j08691, ive tried firefox and chrome. This is the case for all the images in the format above. I have also tried url(/images/topleft.png);

Comment: @user1166981: you mentioned you tried the url in browser directly and it worked , can you share the url for image?

Comment: So, your element isn't show at all. Try to put some text between `<td></td>`.

Comment: @Fire.. that hasn't worked.

Comment: @Nox, test text shows up, but still with no image background

Comment: @user1166981 You use `Inspect element` function of chrome to get image's url, then you compare to your absolute path to get your request !

Comment: Thank you Rong, that did it. There was a symbolic link in place..

Comment: @user1166981 can you take a screenshot ?

Comment: Rong, can you add the answer so I can give you?

Comment: So it wasn't an CSS/HTML problem. Your best shot is to answer yourself and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this HTML:

```
<td class="topleft">&nbsp;</td> <!-- TD not empty, inserting blank space -->
```

and this CSS:

```
td.topleft
{
    border: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(images/topleft.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

verify that the image file name is lower-case, even in the extension. Verify that the `images` folder is lower-cased too. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`background-image: url(./images/topleft.png);`

Answer (score 0):

If your file links and file paths are correct it should work fine.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vc8f6/

To trouble shoot this you should try putting the CSS before the body tag using style tags to make sure the css works properly.  If you still don't see the image check the file paths, spelling (case sensitive) and the extension (.png, .jpg, etc).

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class=topleft width=50 height=50>text goes here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td.topleft{
border:0px;
width: 500px;
height: 150px;
background-image: url(http://www.smiley-faces.org/wallpaper/smiley-face-wallpaper-widescreen-001.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```